# changing arrowhead type in networkx

Tags: python, draw, networkx

I am plotting directed graph using networkx in python. However, I found that arrow head of edge is thick from one end instead of pointed arrow. I want to change the thick edge to pointed arrow. Here is my code, actual output, and desired output:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.DiGraph()

item = [1,2]

G.add_edge(*item) #color = item[-1], weight = 2)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)    
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels = True, edge_color = 'b')   
plt.show()
```

Output
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Any suggestion would be really helpful?

Answer (score 17):

This may be a late answer, but in the new version networkx 2.1 you can set the arrow type by using the **arrowstyle** and **arrowsize** parameter.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.DiGraph()

item = [1,2]

G.add_edge(*item) #color = item[-1], weight = 2)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)    
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels = True, edge_color = 'b', arrowsize=20, arrowstyle='fancy')   
plt.show()
```

You can go to the documentation for details: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges

Answer (score 3):

Good news.  This is possible now with the development version of networkx (will be networkx-2.1).  Your code now now draws arrows

```
In [5]: import networkx as nx
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: 
   ...: G=nx.DiGraph()
   ...: 
   ...: item = [1,2]
   ...: 
   ...: G.add_edge(*item) #color = item[-1], weight = 2)
   ...: 
   ...: pos = nx.circular_layout(G)    
   ...: nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels = True, edge_color = 'b')   
   ...: plt.show()
   ...:
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice feature. Thanks! Is it also possible to control the size of the arrow head?

Comment: So strange, in version 2.4 it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with nx.draw for now. According to https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L584 , it hasn't been implemented yet.

However, you can try to use graphviz to plot your graph. Networkx has an interface to convert your graph to graphviz object easily. See https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.